# MySQL - Select all UNLESS query

Tags: mysql

I have a query that I use the works, but now I need to modify it so that it excludes rows if they have a certain data in a field.

Here's the current code:

```
SELECT oc_ieentry,oc_sysitem,oc_item,oc_itemdesc,oc_purchasedate,oc_url
FROM catalog
WHERE oc_purchasedate >= date_sub(current_date, interval 21 day)
ORDER BY oc_item ASC
```

What I need to do is add a statement in there that if oc_ieentry LIKE 1, then those rows should not be shown.

Comment: you mean `oc_ieentry NOT LIKE 1` I don't know what `LIKE 1` means though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
oc_ieentry,oc_sysitem,oc_item,oc_itemdesc,oc_purchasedate,oc_url 
FROM catalog 
WHERE (oc_purchasedate >= date_sub(current_date, interval 21 day)) 
AND (oc_ieentry NOT LIKE 1) 
ORDER BY oc_item ASC
```

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking about this backwards.

Answer (score 1):

You could add another condition in the `WHERE` clause, such as:

```
SELECT oc_ieentry,oc_sysitem,oc_item,oc_itemdesc,oc_purchasedate,oc_url
FROM catalog
WHERE
    oc_purchasedate >= date_sub(current_date, interval 21 day)
    AND oc_ieentry != 1
ORDER BY oc_item ASC
```

Comment: Technically, `!=` is not compliant with ANSI SQL.  The `<>` operator is the ANSI-correct not-equals operator.  While most popular database systems today support `!=`, it still feels wrong to me.

Comment: I've used MySQL for years and have never encountered an issue with `!=`. T-SQL, yes until semi-recently - but not MySQL. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html also shows support for `!=`.

Comment: It's just personal preference. if you follow only ANSI SQL, you will miss a lot of good stuffs provided by MySQL

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking about this backwards.

Comment: @newfurniturey I didn't say it wouldn't work with MySQL, only that if your goal is to write portable SQL, you should prefer `<>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra condition to your WHERE?

```
...
WHERE oc_purchasedate >= date_sub(current_date, interval 21 day) AND oc_ieentry <> 1
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NOT keyword in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT * from products WHERE prod_price NOT IN (49, 100, 999);
```

Does it help you?